# How to use Docker in sbt-native-packager 0.8.0-M2 with Play

Tags: docker, sbt-native-packager

I am trying to build a Docker image on a Play 2.2 project. I am using Docker version 1.2.0 on Ubuntu Linux.

My Docker specific settings in Build.scala looks like this:

```
dockerBaseImage in Docker := "dockerfile/java:7"
maintainer in Docker := "My name"
dockerExposedPorts in Docker := Seq(9000, 9443)
dockerExposedVolumes in Docker := Seq("/opt/docker/logs")
```

Generated Dockerfile:

```
FROM dockerfile/java:latest
MAINTAINER 
ADD files /
WORKDIR /opt/docker
RUN ["chown", "-R", "daemon", "."]
USER daemon
ENTRYPOINT ["bin/device-guides"]
CMD []
```

Output looks like the dockerBaseImage is being ignored, and the default

```
(dockerfile/java:latest) is not handled correctly:
[project] $ docker:publishLocal
[info] Wrote /..../project.pom
[info] Step 0 : FROM dockerfile/java:latest
[info]  ---> bf7307ff060a
[info] Step 1 : MAINTAINER
[error] 2014/10/07 11:30:12 Invalid Dockerfile format
[trace] Stack trace suppressed: run last docker:publishLocal for the full output.
[error] (docker:publishLocal) Nonzero exit value: 1
[error] Total time: 2 s, completed Oct 7, 2014 11:30:12 AM
[project] $ run last docker:publishLocal
java.lang.RuntimeException: Invalid port argument: last
    at scala.sys.package$.error(package.scala:27)
    at play.PlayRun$class.play$PlayRun$$parsePort(PlayRun.scala:52)
    at play.PlayRun$$anonfun$play$PlayRun$$filterArgs$2.apply(PlayRun.scala:69)
    at play.PlayRun$$anonfun$play$PlayRun$$filterArgs$2.apply(PlayRun.scala:69)
    at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:145)
    at play.PlayRun$class.play$PlayRun$$filterArgs(PlayRun.scala:69)
    at play.PlayRun$$anonfun$playRunTask$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(PlayRun.scala:97)
    at play.PlayRun$$anonfun$playRunTask$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(PlayRun.scala:91)
    at scala.Function7$$anonfun$tupled$1.apply(Function7.scala:35)
    at scala.Function7$$anonfun$tupled$1.apply(Function7.scala:34)
    at scala.Function1$$anonfun$compose$1.apply(Function1.scala:47)
[trace] Stack trace suppressed: run last compile:run for the full output.
[error] (compile:run) Invalid port argument: last
[error] Total time: 0 s, completed Oct 7, 2014 11:30:16 AM
```

What needs to be done to make this work?

I am able to build the image using Docker from the command line:

```
docker build --force-rm -t device-guides:1.0-SNAPSHOT .
```

Comment: Can you give the docker version you are using and the Dockerfile which is created?

Comment: @Muki, I added Docker version and details to question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Packaging/publishing settings are per-project settings, rather than per-build settings.

You were using a `Build.scala` style build, with a format like this:

`object ApplicationBuild extends Build {
      val main = play.Project(appName, appVersion, libraryDependencies).settings(
        ...
      )
    }`

The settings should be applied to this `main` project. This means that you call the `settings()` method on the project, passing in the appropriate settings to set up the packaging as you wish.

In this case:

`object ApplicationBuild extends Build {
      val main = play.Project(appName, appVersion, libraryDependencies).settings(
        dockerBaseImage in Docker := "dockerfile/java:7",
        maintainer in Docker := "My name",
        dockerExposedPorts in Docker := Seq(9000, 9443),
        dockerExposedVolumes in Docker := Seq("/opt/docker/logs")
      )
    }`

To reuse similar settings across multiple projects, you can either create a val of type `Seq[sbt.Setting]`, or extend `sbt.Project` to provide the common settings. See http://jsuereth.com/scala/2013/06/11/effective-sbt.html for some examples of how to do this (e.g. Rule #4).

This placement of settings is not necessarily clear if one is used to using `build.sbt`-type builds instead, because in that file, a line that evaluates to an SBT setting (or sequence of settings) is automatically appended to the root project's settings.

Answer (score 1):

It's a wrong command you executed. I didn't saw it the first time.

```
run last docker:publishLocal
```

remove the **run last**

```
docker:publishLocal
```

Now you get your docker image build as expected

Comment: If you look closely, I start with executing docker:publishLocal. Afterwards I run it with run last, in order to get the error + exception stack trace.

Comment: omfg. you are right. Sorry for that :( Can you provide a small sample project to reproduce this, or is the build.sbt already complete?

Comment: I am using Play 2.2, which might be a problem, as I can get this Play 2.3 app to run easily https://github.com/CloudBees-community/play2-on-beanstalk

Comment: This is an interesting point. Using play 2.3 works? I'm not quite sure if they already added the native-packager-settings completely. try adding the packager_archetype.java_server

Comment: You have your Docker settings inside the Build object, not inside the project (these should be project settings). e.g. put these settings after the `scalacOptions` setting.

Comment: After applying the changes proposed by @Fiadliel it is running fine now. Fiadliel if you create an answer I can accept your answer.